# Fetching gmail inbox using oauth , imap and Authtoken

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, imap, gmail-imap

Hi I'm trying to fetch gmail inbox by IMAP using and the token received from the Android's AccountManager instead of using username and password.

I am trying out with the Google's example of SMTP/IMAP with oauth2 http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fcode%2Fsamples%2Foauth2 http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode

I am able to get the token from below code.

```
    AccountManager accountMan = AccountManager.get(this);
    accountMan.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", token);//old key
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] acc = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    futur = accountManager.getAuthToken(acc[0], "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly" , null, this, new OnTokenAcquired(), null); 


 private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>{
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result)
    {
        try
        {
            Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
            token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("test","token"+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is I am not able to connect to imap and access the inbox.

```
  try{
        IMAPStore imapStore = connectToImap("imap.gmail.com",
                993,
                user,
                oauthToken,
                true);
        Log.e("Successfully authenticated to IMAP"," ");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }




 public static IMAPStore connectToImap(String host,
        int port,
        String userEmail,
        String oauthToken,
        boolean debug) throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
    props.put(OAuth2SaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP, oauthToken);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);


    final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
    IMAPSSLStore store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, unusedUrlName);
    final String emptyPassword = "";
    store.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);


    inbox =  store.getFolder("INBOX");

    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();  
    for (Message message : messages) 
    {  

        try 
        {  
            Log.e("inbox"," "+message.getSubject());  
        }
        catch (MessagingException ex)
        {  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        }

        return store;
      }
}
```

In above code I am not able to connect to store. Not sure where I am going wrong. Please do anybody have related working sample code. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error / exception ?

Comment: there are no errors or any exceptions not even the log in try block of updated question

Comment: You should check out the source of this app .. https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus .. It does the same .. It uses K9 IMAP library. You should use libraries to avoid reinventing the wheel